# Constantly saving content of a dynamically changing webpage which is opened in my browser

Tags: web-scraping, html

I want to keep analyzing text in a dynamically changing webpage -- The content is my login specific and there are no APIs to request the same content by a script.

So the only way I can analyze the content is by opening the page in my browser and then saving the webpage in html(or some other suitable format) and do the analysis on it.

I need to keep doing this analysis every 2-3 seconds. So one way I could think for doing this is that I save the page automatically via a script and analyze the saved content. Can somebody suggest me some ways to save an opened webpage by a script?

Or some other ways to do the analysis I want to do.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Puppeteer](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer), a headless Chrome Node API. That way you can:

1. Navigate to a certain page (or pages) programatically
2. Wait for it to render (since your page is dynamic)
3. Dump its content (in HTML, PDF or other format) to a file
4. Process it the way you want
5. *(Optional)* Include a timer loop (like `setInterval(() => { // Do stuff }, milliseconds)`)

Comment: This way you need not even to damp all the page every 2-3 seconds. You can just poll appropriate fragment of the page (say, via selector) for needed info by an interval or just watch the change automatically.

Comment: Thanks. Are there some similar APIs for firefox?

Comment: Yes, take a look at [Selenium](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium). It supports Firefox